# Using some Loop or repeatable fucntion in AJAX and PHP to reduce repeatability

Tags: php, ajax

I am having a code, in which textbox border color changes, if values exist in wordpress database table. Briefly, if `match1` textbox value exist in `table:xrd_references`, `column:ref_code`, then the `match1` textbox border color green, otherwise red. But I am having many textbox like `match1`, `match2`, `match3`, `match4` and `match5`.
Now I don't want to repeat whole code for all the match textbox, instead if any solution can be suggested. Please take a look at my code.

```html
<?php
global $wpdb; 
if(isset($_POST["match1"])) {
  $query = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xrd_references WHERE ref_code='" . $_POST["match1"] . "'");
    ob_clean();
  if($query>0) {
    echo "<style>#match1{border: 3px solid green;}</style>"; 
  }else{
    echo "<style>#match1{border: 3px solid red;}</style>"; 
  }
    exit;
}
?> 

<input type="text" name="match1" id="match1"/><br>
<input type="text" name="match2" id="match2"/><br>
<input type="text" name="match3" id="match3"/><br>
<input type="text" name="match4" id="match4"/><br>
<input type="text" name="match5" id="match5"/><br>
                
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#match1').on('input', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    data:'match1='+$(this).val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#match1").html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
});});
</script>
```

Comment: This is nothing related to WordPress. Head over to StackOverflow, you may find better response there.

Comment: Sir, I am submitting data to wordpress tables, so I thought I can post it here. If you can please give me some idea to do it.

Comment: Your may work with WordPress but your issue isn't related to it. WordPress provides better way to integrate AJAX calls. For your issue, give the inputs a common css class and call the `input` event on them.